# AngularJS : how to refresh object without data loss?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I have used two different controllers (assume: myCtrl1 and myCtrl2) and I set a button on myCtrl1. When we hit this button the action goes to myCtrl2 via ajax call. Now I'm append some data on .service() object and redirect the page using `$state.go('tabs.myCtrl1)`. Now I can not get the appended data in object. But when app loads the first time it reads empty object in .service().

Anyone help to me

Comment: It would help if you created an illustrative example. Between "go to myCtrl2 via ajax" and "append some data on .service" it's easy to get lost

Comment: You can either create some MainCtrl which would be declared above these two controllers or you can use some service to store the data. Or you use localStorage if you want to store data for longer time

Comment: Thank you Mr.David. I resolve the issue by following your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be the best method but you can store data in $rootscope.variableName which would allow the data to be accessed globally aka it wont get wiped when you switch between controllers